bpy.Mesh.from_pydata create bad faces
I am new to blender scripting so this might be a stupid question. I used scipy to create a spherical voronoi and I want to turn it into a mesh with bpy.Mesh.from_pydata. All the vertices are created fine but the faces are not. Some of the faces are constructed wrongly.
Here's the code
sv = scipy.spatial.SphericalVoronoi(points, 2., np.array([0.,0.,0.]))
mesh = D.meshes.new(name)
mesh.from_pydata(sv.vertices, [], sv.regions)
mesh.update(calc_edges = True)
mesh.validate()

I've checked the scipy part and the output is correct. sv.vertices is a 2D ndarray which looks like this
[[-0.60706175  1.86834282  0.37519477]
 [-1.06915196  1.55572908  0.66077311]
 [-1.58931115  1.15469585 -0.37519004]
 [-1.60521815  1.1662529   0.25125459]
 [ 0.60706175 -1.86834282 -0.37519477]
 [ 1.58931115 -1.15469585  0.37519004]
 [-0.53606837 -0.38947298 -1.88704571]
 [-0.9822388  -0.71364211 -1.58931491]
 [ 0.2047619  -0.63017962 -1.88704696]
 [ 0.37518856 -1.15469072 -1.58931522]
 [ 0.0494932  -1.88704276 -0.6607723 ]
 [-0.8178923  -1.25685037 -1.32339689]
 [-0.07706077 -1.49755803 -1.32339774]
 [-1.96449158  0.          0.37519706]
 [-1.80997808 -0.53606293  0.66076917]
 [-1.80997808  0.53606293  0.66076917]
 [ 1.60521815  1.1662529  -0.25125459]
 [ 0.60706175  1.86834282 -0.37519477]
 [ 1.06915196  1.55572908 -0.66077311]
 [-0.53606837  0.38947298 -1.88704571]
 [-0.9822388   0.71364211 -1.58931491]
 [-0.94259937  1.16624453  1.32339719]
 [-1.40044799  0.53606344  1.32339768]
 [-1.44808435  0.38947221 -1.32339076]
 [-1.44808435 -0.38947221 -1.32339076]
 [-1.7793946  -0.63018927 -0.66076951]
 [-1.7793946   0.63018927 -0.66076951]
 [-1.98415475  0.         -0.25125667]
 [ 1.60521815 -1.1662529  -0.25125459]
 [ 1.06915196 -1.55572908 -0.66077311]
 [ 0.94259937 -1.16624453 -1.32339719]
 [ 0.61313785 -1.88704312  0.25125732]
 [ 1.14920374 -1.49756702  0.66077514]
 [ 0.81789222 -1.2568503   1.323397  ]
 [ 0.66260911  0.         -1.88704774]
 [ 0.94259937  1.16624453 -1.32339719]
 [ 0.2047619   0.63017962 -1.88704696]
 [ 0.37518856  1.15469072 -1.58931522]
 [-0.61313785 -1.88704312 -0.25125732]
 [-1.60521815 -1.1662529   0.25125459]
 [-1.58931115 -1.15469585 -0.37519004]
 [-1.14920374 -1.49756702 -0.66077514]
 [-0.20476176 -0.63017979  1.88704691]
 [-0.66260911  0.          1.88704774]
 [-1.40044799 -0.53606344  1.32339768]
 [-1.21412103  0.          1.58931121]
 [ 1.58931115  1.15469585  0.37519004]
 [-0.8178923   1.25685037 -1.32339689]
 [-0.07706077  1.49755803 -1.32339774]
 [ 0.0494932   1.88704276 -0.6607723 ]
 [-0.61313785  1.88704312 -0.25125732]
 [-1.14920374  1.49756702 -0.66077514]
 [ 1.40044799 -0.53606344 -1.32339768]
 [ 1.21412103  0.         -1.58931121]
 [ 1.40044799  0.53606344 -1.32339768]
 [ 1.80997808  0.53606293 -0.66076917]
 [ 1.96449158  0.         -0.37519706]
 [ 1.80997808 -0.53606293 -0.66076917]
 [ 0.0770608  -1.49755793  1.32339785]
 [-0.37518839 -1.1546907   1.58931528]
 [-0.94259937 -1.16624453  1.32339719]
 [-1.06915196 -1.55572908  0.66077311]
 [-0.0494932  -1.88704276  0.6607723 ]
 [-0.60706175 -1.86834282  0.37519477]
 [ 0.53606836 -0.38947319  1.88704567]
 [ 0.98223865 -0.71364219  1.58931496]
 [-0.20476176  0.63017979  1.88704691]
 [-0.37518839  1.1546907   1.58931528]
 [ 0.53606836  0.38947319  1.88704567]
 [ 0.98223865  0.71364219  1.58931496]
 [ 1.98415475  0.          0.25125667]
 [ 1.7793946  -0.63018927  0.66076951]
 [ 1.7793946   0.63018927  0.66076951]
 [ 1.44808435 -0.38947221  1.32339076]
 [ 1.44808435  0.38947221  1.32339076]
 [ 0.0770608   1.49755793  1.32339785]
 [ 0.81789222  1.2568503   1.323397  ]
 [-0.0494932   1.88704276  0.6607723 ]
 [ 0.61313785  1.88704312  0.25125732]
 [ 1.14920374  1.49756702  0.66077514]]

and sv.regions is a list of list that looks like this:
[[6, 8, 19, 34, 36], [28, 29, 30, 52, 57], [10, 11, 12, 38, 41], [23, 24, 25, 26, 27], [47, 48, 49, 50, 51], [16, 18, 35, 54, 55], [31, 32, 33, 58, 62], [14, 39, 44, 60, 61], [1, 3, 15, 21, 22], [75, 76, 77, 78, 79], [70, 71, 72, 73, 74], [42, 43, 64, 66, 68], [6, 7, 8, 9, 11, 12], [8, 9, 30, 34, 52, 53], [4, 9, 10, 12, 29, 30], [52, 53, 54, 55, 56, 57], [34, 35, 36, 37, 53, 54], [6, 7, 19, 20, 23, 24], [7, 11, 24, 25, 40, 41], [19, 20, 36, 37, 47, 48], [2, 20, 23, 26, 47, 51], [17, 18, 35, 37, 48, 49], [5, 28, 56, 57, 70, 71], [16, 46, 55, 56, 70, 72], [4, 10, 31, 38, 62, 63], [4, 5, 28, 29, 31, 32], [13, 14, 25, 27, 39, 40], [38, 39, 40, 41, 61, 63], [0, 1, 2, 3, 50, 51], [2, 3, 13, 15, 26, 27], [16, 17, 18, 46, 78, 79], [0, 17, 49, 50, 77, 78], [5, 32, 33, 65, 71, 73], [58, 59, 60, 61, 62, 63], [13, 14, 15, 22, 44, 45], [0, 1, 21, 67, 75, 77], [46, 69, 72, 74, 76, 79], [33, 42, 58, 59, 64, 65], [64, 65, 68, 69, 73, 74], [42, 43, 44, 45, 59, 60], [21, 22, 43, 45, 66, 67], [66, 67, 68, 69, 75, 76]]

I am confused as some of the face are constructed correctly but the other's not, and they should be the same. Also the falling cases (i.e. which faces are wrong) seems to be random.

I'm not totally sure, but I think the omission of the edges parameter and then calc_edges=True is what's messing this up. Are you not able to somehow get the edge data from your data source?

Turns out that bpy and bmesh need the vertices indices of a face to be sorted in the spatial order (CCW or CW) to construct the faces correctly, so the below fixes the problem:
sv = scipy.spatial.SphericalVoronoi(points, 2., np.array([0.,0.,0.]))
sv.sort_vertices_of_regions()
mesh = D.meshes.new(name)
mesh.from_pydata(sv.vertices, [], sv.regions)
mesh.update(calc_edges = True)
mesh.validate()


Note CW or CCW will produce inverted normals compared to each other. You can use the overlay in the 3D viewport to see if you have the right one
